# Laravel 4: @include causes Apache (httpd.exe) to crash (on Windows)

Tags: php, apache, laravel

As the title says, there's a certain `@include()` that causes Apache to crash when it's executed.

This is the incriminated code, located in `profile.php`:

```
<hr>
    @include('sections/userInformations', array('userOwner' => $profileUser, 'userVisitor' => $user))
<hr>
```

The `$profileUser` and `$user` come from the `PagesController.php`:

```
public function getProfile($username) {

    return View::make('profile', array(
        'privacy' => Privacy::where('user', '=', $username)->first(),
        'profileUser' => User::where('username', '=', $username)->first(),
        'user' => Auth::user()
    ));
}
```

Apache `error.log`:

```
[Thu Apr 17 18:17:30.840838 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2536:tid 324] AH00428: Parent: child process 1716 exited with status 3221225725 -- Restarting.
[Thu Apr 17 18:17:31.146862 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 2536:tid 324] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Apr 17 18:17:31.183859 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2536:tid 324] AH00455: Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Apr 17 18:17:31.184859 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2536:tid 324] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Nov 21 2013 20:13:01
[Thu Apr 17 18:17:31.184859 2014] [core:notice] [pid 2536:tid 324] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Thu Apr 17 18:17:31.185859 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2536:tid 324] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2904
[Thu Apr 17 18:17:31.627883 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 2904:tid 396] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Apr 17 18:17:31.781898 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 2904:tid 396] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Apr 17 18:17:31.819900 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2904:tid 396] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Thu Apr 17 18:17:33.170971 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2536:tid 324] AH00428: Parent: child process 2904 exited with status 3221225725 -- Restarting.
[Thu Apr 17 18:17:33.482989 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 2536:tid 324] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Apr 17 18:17:33.520991 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2536:tid 324] AH00455: Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Apr 17 18:17:33.520991 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2536:tid 324] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Nov 21 2013 20:13:01
[Thu Apr 17 18:17:33.520991 2014] [core:notice] [pid 2536:tid 324] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Thu Apr 17 18:17:33.522991 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2536:tid 324] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2064
[Thu Apr 17 18:17:33.966015 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 2064:tid 392] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Apr 17 18:17:34.120025 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 2064:tid 392] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Apr 17 18:17:34.159026 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2064:tid 392] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

`PHP_ERROR_LOG` is empty.

Actually there are 2 consequent crashes...

Comment: Anything in the apache error logs?

Comment: Oh yeah, wait a second, I'll make an edit...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Give the following a go:

http://blog.codexpedia.com/apache-server/parent-child-process-exited-with-status-3221225725-restarting-on-xamp-apache/

httpd.conf:

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    ThreadStackSize 8888888
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I just found the solution before reading your answer exactly on that blog. Good catch :)

Answer (score 4):

Your actual error is `[mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2536:tid 324] AH00428: Parent: child process 2904 exited with status 3221225725 -- Restarting.`.

Try searching for `exited with status 3221225725`...

This seems to be a problem on windows,
Try adding the following at the end of apache config file: `httpd.conf`

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
   ThreadStackSize 8388608
</IfModule>
```

then restart apache.